# Docker上のWeb ServerにHostからアクセスするには?

Tags: macos, docker, tcp

Docker上のWeb ServerにHost側のブラウザからアクセスするにはどうすればいいのでしょうか?
Docker for Macを使っており、Web ServerはDockerで動かしているUbuntuの`localhost:3211`で待ち受けています

どうすればmacOSのブラウザからDockerのLinux(Ubuntu)のWeb Serverにアクセスできるのでしょうか?

macOS: 10.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

質問の状況がよくわかっていないのですが、
docker run -p 3211:3211
で解決しますか？